# Impossible to store cocos2d::Animation * in a std::vector of structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, cocos2d-x, std

I work on a project made with cocos2d-x framework (c++).
In my Player class, I have to manage the animations.
Iinitially I had this code that worked without any problem:

First, the animation object is a cocos2d Class `cocos2d::Animation`. Just remember that this object contains a `cocos2d::Vector<AnimationFrame*> _frames;` member.
Doc: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/d3/dc5/classcocos2d_1_1_animation.html#a0fdc0be158df7e09d04644be353db056

```
class Player : public cocos2d::Sprite {
private:
    cocos2d::Map<std::string, cocos2d::Animation*> animations;
    cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::SpriteFrame*> getAnimation(const char *format, int frameStart, int count);
    void update(float delta) override;
    bool init() override;

public:
    static Player* create();
    bool init() override;
    //...
};
```

And the implementation side:

```
bool Player::init() {
    //...
    animations.insert("idleN", Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(getAnimation("%04d", 207, 9), 0.1));
    //...
}

Vector<SpriteFrame*> Player::getAnimation(const char *format, int frameStart, int count) {
    auto spriteCache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
    Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames;
    char str[100] = {0};
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        sprintf(str, format, frameStart);
        log("%s", str);
        animFrames.pushBack(spriteCache->getSpriteFrameByName(str));
        frameStart++;
    }
    return animFrames;
}

//later in the code execution
void Player::manageIdle() {
        auto idleAnim = Animate::create(animations[0].anim);
        runAction(idleAnim);
}
```

You can see each Animation is contained in `cocos2d::Map<std::string, cocos2d::Animation*>` and as I say before, this code worked perfectly, no error.

---

But I needed some more informations in addition to the name and the object itself so I decided to use a structure to store all infos for each animation. And I replaced the `cocos2d::Map<std::string, cocos2d::Animation*>` by `std::vector<animData>` with `animData` as structure. I refactored the code like so:

```
class Player : public cocos2d::Sprite {
public:
    typedef struct animation {
        std::string name;
        cocos2d::Animation* anim;
        //all others info needed, not relevant here, (just several enum type variables)
    } animData;
private:
    std::vector<animData > animations;  //the new container
    //rest of code stay unchanged
};
```

The changes in the implementation side:

```
bool Player::init() {
    //...
    animations.push_back({"idleN", Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(getAnimation("%04d", 207, 9), 0.1)});
    //no problem here...
}
```

But now, when I try to create a new anim with a animation saved in my container (vector) I get a SegV on this line:

```
void Player::manageIdle() {
        auto idleAnim = Animate::create(animations[0].anim); //SegV here, in Animate::create() funct
        runAction(idleAnim);
}
```

After search, I find that each structure member `anim` which is type of cocos2d::Animation*, now conatains a empty `cocos2d::Vector<AnimationFrame*> _frames;` and there is the problem !
It’s as if they lose the `cocos2d::Vector<AnimationFrame*>` ref or something like that.

**So my question is why `cocos2d::Vector<AnimationFrame*>` become empty with my refactored code and not whith the previous one ?**

I found this with test like that:

```
auto test = animList[0].anim->getFrames();
if (test.empty()) {
    log("empty"); //The test output empty
}
```

Debugguer screen in the end of the init() funct:

[image]

Debugguer screen in Player::manageIdle() funct:

[image]

---

**Edit:** when I add `animations.back().anim->retain();` right after the line to add an element in the vector, it solves the problem !

```
animations.push_back({"idleN", Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(getAnimation("%04d", 207, 9), 0.1)});
animations.back().anim->retain();
```

Because `cocos2d::Animation*` inherit from cocos2d::Ref, it is an auto-release object. When used inside a cocos2d container like cocos2d::Map or cocos2d::Vector, it is auto managed by the container itself. But I use a std::vector so I lose the ref I think. Something like that.
Now I need to find a way to get rid of this additional line of code because this multiple by twice my number of line here !

So new question here: **How I can get rid of the fact I have to call `animations.back().anim->retain();` each time I add a new element in my vector ?**

Comment: So right after `init()` and with no intervening calls, calling `manageIdle()` produces this error?  Or are you making other function calls in-between those two calls, and you're not disclosing this information?  Objects you claim are created just don't vanish by magic.

Comment: If I call `manageIdle()` right after the `push_back` line in the `init()` funct, it works well. But the second call, the problem occurs. Because the code execution leaved the `init()` funct, and someting at this moment goes wrong. No other function calls between this two calls. You have the entire code logic here.

Comment: Not really enough code to see the flow, but `Vector<SpriteFrame*> Player::getAnimation` is returning a copy of a vector. If `Animation::createWithSpriteFrames` is expecting that vector to remain valid then you have a problem, because the returned temporary immediately goes out of scope at the end of that line.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you are right, I edited my post. Olaf Dietsche sorry but what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I missed the second definition of `class Player`.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a wrapper around `Ref`, which "retains" ownership, and store this wrapper instead, sort of a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) e.g.

```
template<typename T> class RefOwner {
public:
    RefOwner(T *t) : ref(t) {
        ref->retain();
    }

    ~RefOwner() {
        ref->release();
    }

    T *operator->() { return ref; }
private:
    T *ref;
};
```

and then use it as

```
struct animData {
    std::string name;
    RefOwner<cocos2d::Animation> anim;
    //all others info needed, not relevant here, (just several enum type variables)
};
```

---

Disclaimer: I have no experience with cocos2d-x, just looked at [`Animation`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/d3/dc5/classcocos2d_1_1_animation.html) and [`Ref`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/df/d28/classcocos2d_1_1_ref.html)